# Time-Efficient Sorting of structure in c++

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a structure

```
 struct abc
       {
        int p;
        int q;
       }
```

and a file which gives the value of p and q and the operation that is to be done( insert,delete or modify) and then accordingly the values needs to be maintained in a sorted manner(sort acc to p).
The sequence is

```
1.Read the line from file
2.If insert, insert in a sorted manner<br>   
  If modify,delete; first remove the element and then sort<br>
3.Repeat step 1<br><br>
```

I already implemented this with a linked list but is there any other more time-efficient method than this?
I thought of an array(with memcpy-ing to ease the operations),set and vector but implementation wise it seems to be a bit difficult as all the operations has to done.
Would be helpful if i could get an algorithm or snapshot of the code

Comment: What do you mean with *"all the operations has to done"*? And what is wrong with `std::set<abc>`? How have you measured that it is not efficient enough?

Comment: As set keys are `const`, you have to remove and readd it if you want to change the key.

Comment: In c++, using vectors/arrays tends to be much faster (and simpler) than linked lists. Even if you have to std::sort() them every time you're done inserting.

Comment: Unless you always insert and remove in the same location, almost anything is better than a linked list. The reason linked lists are taught early in schools is that they provide a convenient introduction to working with pointers. In practice, they're only useful in rare special cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can use array of structure to get input and then use built-in sort according to a compare function.

```
bool compare(struct abc c1,struct abc c2)
{ 
 return c1.p < c2.p;
}


//main
abc arr[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
 cin>>arr[i].p>>arr[i].q;
}
//O(n lg n)
sort(arr,arr+n,compare);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to implement many operations.

Define your ordering relation:

```
bool operator<(const abc& lhs, const abc& rhs) { return lhs.p < rhs.p; }
```

Read the data:

```
std::vector<abc> data;
abc x;
while (whatever >> x.p >> x.q)
{
    data.push_back(x);
}
```

Sort the data:

```
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
```

Insert while maintaining the order

```
abc y = whatever;
data.insert(std::lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), y), y);
```